# Ordered Message processing in JBoss

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss7.x, message-driven-bean

I have a couple of JBoss 7.4.3 instances running in standalone mode which will try to consume messages from Tibco ESB using the [Generic JMS JCA RA](https://github.com/jms-ra/generic-jms-ra).

As there are multiple JBoss instances the messages will be processed in parallel. I want to process the messages sequentially based on the business key after they are consumed.

For example, "Order 1" business key messages should be processed in one node, irrespective of whether it is consumed in other nodes. Likewise "Order 2" shall be processed on other nodes.

In Weblogic the same is achieved using "unit of order." One MDB consumes the message and sends it to the internal queue with a unit of order set, then the WebLogic takes care of sending particular key messages to the same WebLogic instance.

Comment: Does Tibco support JMS message grouping?

Comment: I am using 7.4.3.

Comment: Are you using JBoss AS for JBoss EAP?